# How to send cross domain requests from client to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Google Drive API but while retrieving data from client side I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load url.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Note that I am not allowed to change headers.

Is there a way to request cross domain?

```
var req = {
    action: 'getFiles',
};  

this.getJSON('drive.php', req, function(serverData)
{
    console_log(serverData);

});
```

Above code gives this error. How can I solve this problem?

One option:

```
var url = 'drive.php';


$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    data: {action: 'getFiles'},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json.sites);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Still it gives GET error

Comment: You need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your response header with the domain name or use `*` for global.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to set headers?  Note that the client has this restriction; you should be able to make the request from the server without issue, and thus could do CLIENT -> SERVER -> GOOGLE DRIVE

Comment: I am not allowed to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request using JSONP; see the following for examples.  http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

An example from that site:

```
(function($) {
var url = 'http://www.jquery4u.com/scripts/jquery4u-sites.json?callback=?';


    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
           console.dir(json.sites);
        },
        error: function(e) {
           console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

    })(jQuery)

;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The cross domain request is not allowed for security reasons. What you can do is the following:

Write a PHP script which just forwards your request and place this PHP script in the same server as  your JavaScript. Your JS will thereby perform the request on the domain and will not end up with an error.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In php you need

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST/GET');
```

insert into header file .php, it's allow client POST data with method POST/GET to server and get receiver from it ...